# Configure Outlook not to hide attachments

Tags: email, outlook, attachment

How do you configure Outlook to display *all* (incl. unsafe) mail attachments?

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft describe the solution in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829982) and lists *all* blocked attachments [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA012299521033.aspx). As there is no way to say "unblock all" you need to specify every possible type that may be blocked. e.g.

Office 2007 Example  (copy/paste into a .reg file)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Security]
"Level1Remove"=".ade;.adp;.app;.asp;.bas;.bat;.cer;.chm;.cmd;.cnt;.com;.cpl;.crt;.csh;.der;.exe;.fxp;.gadget;.hlp;.hpj;.hta;.inf;.ins;.isp;.its;.js;.jse;.ksh;.lnk;.mad;.maf;.mag;.mam;.maq;.mar;.mas;.mat;.mau;.mav;.maw;.mda;.mdb;.mde;.mdt;.mdw;.mdz;.msc;.msh;.msh1;.msh2;.mshxml;.msh1xml;.msh2xml;.msi;.msp;.mst;.ops;.osd;.pcd;.pif;.plg;.prf;.prg;.pst;.reg;.scf;.scr;.sct;.shb;.shs;.ps1;.ps1xml;.ps2;.ps2xml;.psc1;.psc2;.tmp;.url;.vb;.vbe;.vbp;.vbs;.vsmacros;.vsw;.ws;.wsc;.wsf;.wsh;.xnk;"
```

Answer (score 0):

See this solution (http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_force_outlook_to_open_potentially_unsafe_attachments_that_i_know_are_ok.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.